# 'Cannot read property 'color1' of undefined' error in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, storyblok

I am making a website with storyblok, vue and nuxt. In my component, I am trying to change the background color of the component by getting a value out of the storyblok API and getting the right HEX code in my object. 
However, I can't seem to find what is going wrong, I am getting this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'color1' of undefined
at VueComponent.backgroundColor (app.js:6239)
at Watcher.get (commons.app.js:25459)
at Watcher.evaluate (commons.app.js:25564)
at VueComponent.computedGetter [as backgroundColor] (commons.app.js:25814)
at Object.get (commons.app.js:23107)
at Proxy.render (app.db592a6f79c830fedfca.hot-update.js:55)
at VueComponent.Vue._render (commons.app.js:24557)
at VueComponent.updateComponent (commons.app.js:25048)
at Watcher.get (commons.app.js:25459)
at Watcher.run (commons.app.js:25534)
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this error. 
This is my code:

The div I am trying to change the background color of:

```
<div class="column image" :style="{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor}">
    <div class="image" :style="{ paddingTop: getRatio }">
        <img class="lazyload" :src="blok.image"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

My object in the data() function:

```
methods: {

        data()
        {
            return {
                colors: {
                    color1: '#ffffff',
                    color2: '#5646F2',
                    color3: '#000000'
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

My computed function:

```
backgroundColor() {
    return !this.blok.color ? this.colors.color1 : this.colors[this.blok.color];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this causes a problem, but the `data()` field should be outside the `methods` in order for the vue template to use the values

Comment: You've defined `data` inside the `methods` object.

Comment: Maybe you have lost context `this` in `backgroundColor` function, in this case you should bind function or use arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.colors` is undefined because your `data()` is inside the `methods` hook. Define the `data` hook outside the `methods` hook.

When you look for `this.colors`, it will look for the property `colors` defined inside the `data` hook. And when you look for a method for eg. `this.myMethod()`, it will look for the method inside the `methods` or `computed` hook as necessary.